# Receiving "The page cannot be dispayed" error in browser when viewing IIS web site

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis-6, asp.net, .net

I have configured an asp.net site in IIS 6.0 with the following settings.

- Allow anonymous access = true
- Set host header, directory path, port, and IP
- In asp.net tab - asp.net 2.0
- In web.config added: `<add path="*" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" type="System.Web.DefaultHttpHandler" validate="True" />`
- Enable default content page = true
- Permission settings fine
- Integrated Windows authentication = true

When I browse it in IIS I then got the error "The page cannot be displayed ... Cannot find server or DNS Error" What may cause this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to wait for dns propagation.. make sure your domain is pointing to the iis server.

go to this website to test dns errors.

[www.intodns.com](http://www.intodns.com)